# How to generate a DTO java class from a file?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a file like this with many lines:

```
Var1Name | Var1Type | Var1Description
Var2Name | Var2Type | Var2Description
...
```

Is it possible to generate a class like this using a template/tool ...?

```
public class ${NAME}{
    /*
     * ${Var1Description}
     */
    private ${Var1Type} ${Var1Name};

        public ${Var1Type} get${Var1Name}() {
            return ${Var1Name};
        }

        public void set${Var1Name}(${Var1Type} ${Var1Name}) {
            this.${Var1Name} = ${Var1Name};
        }

    /*
     * ${Var2Description}
     */
    private ${Var2Type} ${Var2Name};

        public ${Var2Type} get${Var2Name}() {
            return ${Var2Name};
        }

        public void set${Var2Name}(${Var2Type} ${Var2Name}) {
            this.${Var2Name} = ${Var2Name};
        }

    ...
}
```

My IDE is intellij and I tried to customize "File and code templates" for my purpose but I could not read the file.

Any suggestions? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [IntelliJ Ultimate](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-transfer-objects.html) can do that. Most ORMs will also have such a feature. I personally use [JOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.11/manual/getting-started/tutorials/jooq-in-7-steps/jooq-in-7-steps-step3/), which is not an ORM but a "typesafe SQL in Java" tool (and more).

Comment: Thanks assylias, in the end I can not use a table. The list of variables is contained in a file (perhaps csv).
I can not figure out how to use it, in the EJB tool window if I click - new I read only Stateless / Stateful Session Bean, Singleton Session Bean, Message Bean, and Interceptor (I read that from version 3.0 entity Bean have been deprecated).
I can not find clear documentation about it....